# Relaxation - spreadsheet solution to recursive algorithm

Tags: numerical-modelling

I am setting up a simple model that uses recursion to iterate between known constraints - relaxation, in other words. I need a spreadsheet that allows:

```
A0 50

A1 =(A0+A2)/2

A2 =(A1+A3)/2

A3 =(A2+A4)/2

A4 100
```

It should be simple, but OpenOffice and Apple Numbers specifically forbid this. If you know of configuration setting to override this, that would be great too.

Comment: You can compute the iteration in different columns, that way you don't have recursion. I have used to implement Euler's method. Another option is to use a scripting language like Python (I don't know what are the options for Apple counterpart).

Comment: I think you are struggling with the difference between iteration and bad references.  If for row 1 you have the initial values, then in row2 you can have the equations for A1...A3 that you are looking for.

Comment: You only need to break the "circular reference" in one place.  `A0` and `A4` are given (constants), so we can omit them from the circle (i.e. just put their fixed values into the computation; they don't depend on `A1,A2,A3` whatsoever.  So (for example) put a starting value in for `A1` in (for the sake of irony) cell A1, the formula for `A2` in A2, and the formula for `A3` in A3.  Then in cell B1 (next to cell A1), put the formula for `A1`.  By updating the value in cell A1 for `A1` with the computed value in cell B1, you can observe the successive convergence of entries.